# How to sort a pandas dataframe by columns and a part of multi index simultaneously without modifying the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Given:

```
mi1 = MultiIndex.from_tuples([('bar', 'y'), ('bar', 'z'), ('baz', 'y'), ('baz', 'z'), ('foo', 'y'), ('foo', 'z')])

dfa = DataFrame(random.rand(6),index=mi1)
```

How to sort by some columns and some levels of a multi index simultaneously (in this case let's say level 1 of the multiindex and then by column 0

I know that I could propagate the partial multiindices to columns:

```
dfa[1] = zip(*dfa.index)[1]
dfa.sort(columns=[1,0])
```

But how to do the sort without this propagation step?

@user2360798 had a similar question but noone answered the simultaneous sorting of column/index part of the question: 
[Sort pandas dataframe both on values of a column and index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277358/sort-pandas-dataframe-both-on-values-of-a-column-and-index)

Comment: What do you mean by simultaneously, you would have to give priority to either the index or the column right? So `dfa.sort([0]).sortlevel(level=1)` or in reversed order `dfa.sortlevel(level=1).sort([0])`.

Comment: You are correct, sorry about that.  I meant sort by level 1 then by column 0 in case of ties in level 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy if you reset the index.

Construct your index with names (not necessary but more informative)

```
In [23]: mi1 = MultiIndex.from_tuples([('bar', 'y'), ('bar', 'z'), ('baz', 'y'), ('baz', 'z'), ('foo', 'y'), ('foo', 'z')],names=['first','second'])

In [24]: dfa = DataFrame(np.random.randn(6),index=mi1)

In [25]: dfa
Out[25]: 
                          0
first second               
bar   y       0.18574062599
      z      -0.82120720368
baz   y      -0.05645183973
      z      -1.07579609513
foo   y      -1.03528813447
      z      -0.46439965218

[6 rows x 1 columns]
```

Reset makes all of the indices into columns, sort, then revert

```
In [26]: dfa.reset_index().sort(columns=['second',0]).set_index(dfa.index.names)
Out[26]: 
                          0
first second               
foo   y      -1.03528813447
baz   y      -0.05645183973
bar   y       0.18574062599
baz   z      -1.07579609513
bar   z      -0.82120720368
foo   z      -0.46439965218

[6 rows x 1 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

For pandas `0.23.0` is possible sort [columns and index levels together](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#sorting-by-a-combination-of-columns-and-index-levels):

```
mi1 = pd. MultiIndex.from_tuples([('bar', 'y'), ('bar', 'z'), ('baz', 'y'), ('baz', 'z'), ('foo', 'y'), ('foo', 'z')],names=['first','second'])

dfa = pd.DataFrame({'col':[1,4,5,6,1,2]},index=mi1)
```

---

```
print (dfa)
              col
first second     
bar   y         1
      z         4
baz   y         5
      z         6
foo   y         1
      z         2

df = dfa.sort_values(['second','col'])
print (df)
              col
first second     
bar   y         1
foo   y         1
baz   y         5
foo   z         2
bar   z         4
baz   z         6
```