# How should i post my output of a DataFrame from my juptyer notebook in Stack overflow post?

Tags: python, dataframe, copy, paste

I tried copy - pasting the output of the dataframe from the jupyter notebook in the question followed by `Ctrl+K` command,

However this happend,

```
SUMLEV  REGION  COUNTY  STNAME  CTYNAME CENSUS2010POP   ESTIMATESBASE2010
0   50  3   1   Alabama Autauga County  54571   54571
1   50  3   3   Alabama Baldwin County  182265  182265
2   50  3   5   Alabama Barbour County  27457   27457
3   50  4   3   Arizona Cochise County  131346  131357
4   50  4   5   Arizona Coconino County 134421  134437
5   50  4   7   Arizona Gila County 53597   53597
6   50  4   21  California  Glenn County    28122   28122
7   50  4   23  California  Humboldt County 134623  134623
8   50  4   25  California  Imperial County 174528  174528
```

**Actual Dataframe:**

[image]

But as you can see from the above, the table gets jumbled. Editing it line by line will consume a lot of time. Is there a fast way to do this? I know I could just upload the snipshots but still if i could just copy-paste the output quickly without taking snapshots again and again.

People have done this, see [How to sort a pandas dataframe by columns and a part of multi index simultaneously without modifying the dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613844/how-to-sort-a-pandas-dataframe-by-columns-and-a-part-of-multi-index-simultaneous)

In the above link, if you check the answer of the question that has been accepted then you can see that the dataframe is intact, just as it would be in a jupyter notebook output and the guy who wrote the answer also paste the input and output cells as it is from the notebook. I want to do the same.

Comment: So problem is with display? Why it is important?

Comment: Well because with larger dataframes one won't we able to understand the data at all, the one in the question above can still be understood as it is not very large. And if i cannot convey my data properly then i cannot convey my question.

Comment: hmmm, is possible create [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) without large dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just display your dataframe, only writing its name like this:

```py
dataframe
```

You can actually print your dataframe with the **print** function:

```py
print(dataframe)
```

This will give you a text-edited output that should respect the tabulations of the dataframe. Once you copy it here, use the block code so it will be automatically formatted.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the index from the output of your dataframe in your jupyter notebook using this code `print(df.to_string(index=False))`

After that you can simply copy - paste the output of your dataframe from the jupyter notebook in stack overflow post.