# Efficiently Reorder DataFrame of Lists/Pairings

Tags: python, pandas

I have an efficiency question. Essentially I have a dataframe filled with lists. Each list contains a value and a string describing that value (I assumed that a list format would be the easiest way to sort pairings). I need to separately reorder the values in each row with the highest value to the left and the lowest value to the right. I have found a solution to this, but given that I am a newer programmer, I wanted to know if you believe there is a quicker way of doing this operation without iterating through the indexes. Please feel free to provide any sort of feedback that you have. The only requirement I have is that the final solution is a dataframe where a value is immediately followed by its string descriptor (the string descriptor could be in its own adjacent column, doesn't need to be in a list).

Starting DF:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
master_stop = pd.DataFrame([[[56,'Support'],[58, 'MA']],
                            [[24.4, 'Support'],[23.3,'MA'],[25,'MA']]],
                           ['Symbol_1','Symbol_2']).fillna(np.NaN)
master_stop

Out[2]: 
                        0           1         2
Symbol_1    [56, Support]    [58, MA]       NaN
Symbol_2  [24.4, Support]  [23.3, MA]  [25, MA]
```

Sorting Method That I'm Looking to Improve:

```
def sort_df():
    for index in master_stop.index:
        master_stop.loc[index] = master_stop.loc[index].sort_values(ascending=False).values
```

Sorted DF:

```
sort_df()
master_stop
Out[3]: 
                 0                1           2
Symbol_1  [58, MA]    [56, Support]         NaN
Symbol_2  [25, MA]  [24.4, Support]  [23.3, MA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `stack`, `sort_values`, `sort_index` and `unstack` can do the job. Not in one line but if you do

```
master_stack = master_stop.stack().sort_index(level=0,ascending=[True])
master_stop = (pd.Series(data = master_stack.sort_values(ascending=False).sort_index(level=0,ascending=[True]).values,
                         index = master_stack.index)
                 .unstack())
```

then `master_stop` will be sorted as expected

```
                 0                1           2
Symbol_1  [58, MA]    [56, Support]         NaN
Symbol_2  [25, MA]  [24.4, Support]  [23.3, MA]
```

Comment: This solution works for the two symbols but when I run it AFTER the code below, which increases the number of instances in master stop, I get a wild unsorted DF (Sorry, don't know how to make indents on comments for code).
 `for i in range(100):
    master_stop.loc[i,0] = [100,'Support']
    master_stop.loc[i,1] = [102,'MA']`

Comment: @Whip indeed, sorry I fixed my error by adding `sort_index`. See the code is edited. You can also have a look at `groupby` but I think using `sort_index` will be faster is you have a lot of rows in your original dataframe

Comment: Thank you! I can indeed confirm that your code is an improvement. My original code using an additional 100 entries ran at approx. 144ms, while yours is running at 88ms, providing a substantial improvement. Before I accept your answer, I plan on leaving the question open a bit longer in case anybody else has any unique alternative solutions.

Comment: @Whip good :) and I would guess that the gain in time will increase with the number of rows.

Comment: Quick follow-up question! Why did you have to put []s around the second 'True' statement in the second line when you call sort_index? I notice that in the first master_stack line, the []s around True didn't make a difference in output, but in the second line having the brackets around [True] makes a big difference in the output. I'm guessing its function specific since sort_values didn't require []s around the False call....but i couldn't find anything in the pandas documentation.

Comment: It looks like if you don't have the []s it will sort all index levels? Whether you declare index level=0 beforehand or not. Why is that?

Comment: @Whip yesterday when you pointed out that my mistake, I understood that I missed to `groupby` on the first level of index. Although it can be practical in a lot of case, here it seemed limited for speed purpose. So I look for a way to sort at the same time on a column and an index as it does the job, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277358/sort-pandas-dataframe-both-on-values-of-a-column-and-index) gives answers, especially this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50107507/9274732).

Comment: @Whip now to fully explain why, I can't answer that, I would say by adding `[]`, then you sort the index by keeping the values in the columns associated to each index, while if you don't then the index will be sorted while the values not. but it's just what I understood from it.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Ben!