# Sort_values Pandas to sort by index?

Tags: pandas, sorting, indexing

I know that sort_index() lets me sort a df by the index, but I am wondering if sort_values() can sort by the index too (without resetting the index)?

Answer (score 5):

No, sort_values can't sort the by index without converting first converting the index to a column (possibly with reset_index).  The typical way to sort by index, as you have mentioned, is via the sort_index method.  Links to the documentation for the relevant methods is given below.

- [pandas.DataFrame.sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)
- [pandas.DataFrame.sort_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html)

Comment: This is incorrect as of Pandas 0.23. As long as the index has a name it can be included in the list of columns to sort by.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, as balast mentioned, you would need to convert the index to a column:

```
df = df.rename_axis('MyIdx').sort_values(by = ['MyCol', 'MyIdx'], ascending = [False, True])
```

More info on [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52720936/12534623)

Comment: Wait a minute, but you are showing that you don't have to convert the index to a column. Your approach just gives the index a name, you are still using sort values, right?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment above, you can give the index a name and use that in `sort_values`:

```
> import pandas as pd
> df = pd.DataFrame([2,1,3], index=[2,1,3])   
> df.index.name='myindex'
> df.sort_values('myindex') 
myindex   
1        1
2        2
3        3
```